# How to select all records in a DropDownList

Tags: asp.net, select, drop-down-menu

I have this DropDownList:

```c#
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" 
    runat="server" 
    AutoPostBack="true" 
    DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" 
    DataTextField="Categorie" 
    DataValueField="Cat_ID" 
>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

and the SqlDataSource `select * all from [tbl_Cat]`

It's used to filter the database via category. It works perfectly, but it only shows the three categories that are in the `tbl_Cat`. I also want a `select all` item in the DropDownList.

The DropDownList and the datagrid are not made with code-behind; is it possible to enter a "select all records" option through code-behind?

Answer (score 1):

You need to write the below code which help you to select all option for category.

```
 <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" AutoPostBack="true" runat="server">
 </asp:DropDownList>
```

In Code behind file

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(str);
string com = "select * all from tbl_Cat";
SqlDataAdapter adpt = new SqlDataAdapter(com, con);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
adpt.Fill(dt);

DropDownList1.DataSource = dt;
DropDownList1.DataBind();
DropDownList1.DataTextField = "Categorie";
DropDownList1.DataValueField = "Cat_ID";
DropDownList1.DataBind();
DropDownList1.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Select ALL", "0"));
```

Now you can check if drop down selected value is 0, if it is 0 then you can load all the records in the grid.

Let me know if any thing i miss.

Comment: it says : Compiler Error Message: BC30188: Declaration expected. At:`SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(str);`

Answer (score 0):

following is the way to bind DropDownList from codebehind. visit [this link](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/rohatash/binding-dropdownlist-with-database-and-display-data-in-gridv/) for details

```
 <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server">
 </asp:DropDownList>
```

**CODE BEHIND**

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(str);
string com = "select * all from tbl_Cat";
SqlDataAdapter adpt = new SqlDataAdapter(com, con);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
adpt.Fill(dt);

DropDownList1.DataSource = dt;
DropDownList1.DataBind();
DropDownList1.DataTextField = "Categorie";
DropDownList1.DataValueField = "Cat_ID";
DropDownList1.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 0):

May be you have this query,

```
DropDownList1.Items.Add(new ListItem("Select All", "0"));
```