# "Select All" option for more than one drop-down list in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu

I have two drop-down list in which one is "State" and another is "Cluster". Both of these drop-down list are relational. For example if I select Kerala in State then Cluster will populate its important cities and dist. like Pathnamthitta, calicut, palakad etc.

So, what I want is, I want to give an option "Select All" in both State and Cluster ddl.

I've gone through:

[How to select all records in a DropDownList](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16191005/select-all-record-asp-net-dropdownlist)

http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/control_dropdownlist.asp

http://forums.asp.net/t/1221977.aspx?Adding+a+Select+all+option+to+a+drop+down+list

But none of them worked for me. I can able to have select all in state but not getting cluster values populated on the other ddl.

This is my code for "State" ddl:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
if (!IsPostBack)
{
DataSet3TableAdapters.tbl_energy_reportTableAdapter state;
state = new DataSet3TableAdapters.tbl_energy_reportTableAdapter();
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt = state.GetDataByStateInnerJoin();
DropDownList1.DataSource = dt;
DropDownList1.DataTextField = "state1";
DropDownList1.DataValueField = "state1";
DropDownList1.DataBind();                
DropDownList1.Items.Insert(0, new System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem("--Select State--", "0"));
DropDownList2.Items.Insert(0, new System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem("--Select Cluster--", "0"));
}
}
```

And This code is for "Cluster"

```
protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

DataSet3TableAdapters.tbl_energy_reportTableAdapter state;
state = new DataSet3TableAdapters.tbl_energy_reportTableAdapter();
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt = state.GetDataByClusterInnerJoin(DropDownList1.SelectedValue);
DropDownList2.DataSource = dt;
DropDownList2.DataTextField = "cluster";
DropDownList2.DataValueField = "cluster";
DropDownList2.DataBind();

}
```

Any help will be much appreciated....

Comment: I am not getting your question Exactly , because you mentioned that you want "Select All" option in both but how can user select all "States" and how can you display Cities according to all selected State ??? .... user should only one 'State' at a time.

Comment: According to our requirement this is a report generating App. So sometimes user need to get all the details printed. For this I need to give select all option for both the State and Cluster. And it can be possible to select a state and under that select all "Cluster" values. Thats the reason why I asked for having select all option for both the drop-down list.